# How to pass hashmap values to model class constructor in java

Tags: java, android

I am learning android and I want to show the values from firebase Db into a recyclerview in my app.

I have a pojo class like,

[image]

And I got the iteration value from firebase like shown in below picture.

You can see that each entity of my model class is coming as a Hashmap key.

How should i iterate through this, so that i can pass the values to my model class constructor and thereby add the model class to my recyclerview adapter list.

.
.
.
.

[image]

Comment: Please copy the code as `text` to the question, rather than pictures. We can copy and run code as text, but not pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your HashMap is always with the size of 3 and you know the key names, then you can just do the following.

```
UserInfo info = new UserInfo(map.get("referralName"), map.get("referralContact"), map.get("referralType"));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But my hashmap size is not always 3. It will vary. Anyway ll workout your method and come back.

Comment: If your hashmap here is of different size, then I'd say your DB design needs some improviement. Otherwise you can iterate through the keys of the hashmap and look for the first ones that match your requirements, but if you have many users and your hashmaps contain a lot of unnecessary info, then you are transferring a lot of unnecessary data.

Comment: Yes understood, BTW like @rzwitserloot said can i also use gson here?

Comment: Yes, I don't see why not. You can annotate your POJO and then use GSON to deserialize the JSONObject or JSONArray.

Answer (score 2):

You need a so-called 'marshalling' library which turns JSON into java POJOs.

The commonly used libraries are [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) ... for normal java. For android? Possibly something is baked in. Perhaps GSON, which is authored by google.